# What would be the English translation of "Модифицированный дополнительный код"?

Tags: перевод

In the context of binary numbers, what would be the English translation of "Модифицированный дополнительный код"? What the "Модифицированный дополнительный код" representation of a binary number? Google translate tells me that it means "Modified Additional Code", but I am not sure what it is.

Also, what about the expression "Модифицированный обратный код". Again, Google translate tells me that it means "Modified Reverse Code", but I still don't get what would this be.

Comment: Модифицированный [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) — *modified two's complement*, модифицированный [обратный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) — *modified one's complement*.

Comment: @Arhad Ok, thanks! And what would that mean? Modified two's complement, e.g.? I never heard of this.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about calculations, then <<Дополнительный код>> is “two’s complement”, <<Обратный код>> is “ones' complement”. To understand what “modified” means, I need to see the context.
Less likely, but it may be a telegraph code (eg. modified Baudot code or <<МТК-2>>; see https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%A2%D0%9A-2).